# open html file with onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm a rookie at javascript. I'm trying to open an html file in the same directory when clicking an image. (My image displays but the onclick function doesn't work).

```
projects = document.createElement('div');
projects.style.position = 'absolute';
projects.innerHTML = '<img src="image.png" class="projectspage" style="display:block; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 100px; background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 100px;" />';
projects.onClick = function() {
  window.open('projects.html')
};

uiContainer.appendChild(projects);
```

Comment: do you get an error? it's possible that you have a popup blocker running.

Comment: no i have no error or any indication that the button doesn't work. the console comes out with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
projects.onClick = function() {
  window.location.href = 'valid-location-like-host.com/index.php
};
```

I'm assuming you mean redirect to a new page in the browser on click.  The above is the correct way to implement that in pure js.

Comment: "I'm assuming..." Why not just ask with a comment?

Comment: I tried exactly that but it doesn't work. When selecting the image, it seems like no event is being triggered.

Comment: Actually you need to change href propertie, so you write it like: `window.location.href = 'valid-location-like-host.com/index.php'` or similar. Please edit your answer and it will be ok user2263572.

Comment: @Marco i've tried to do that although it still doesn't triggger any event.

Comment: Acuatlly it doesn't trigger any event, what it will do is redirect to that page. The code is valid for sure. Maybe if you provide a minimum working example we can help you more?

Comment: For some reason i found that this would work   projects.addEventListener('click', function () {

      window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';

    }, false);